# Implicit Declaration of Function 'If'

Tags: c++, c

*I'm currently trying to create a quick program that will give you the chance to guess a predetermined number (I want that number to be 28) in 10 guesses only. If you meet the guess, you will be told "Congrats! You have guessed the number." If you do not meet the guess, you will be told "Try Again!" until you run out of tries or get the guess right.*

***Here is my current code:***
int main(void) {

```
int Chance, Guess;
printf ("You have 10 chances to guess the number between 0-50.\n");
for (Chance=0; Chance<10; Chance++)
{
    scanf("%d",&Guess);
    If (Guess==28)
        printf("Congrats! You have guess the number!");
    Else If (Guess!=28)
        printf("Try Again!\n");
    }
printf("You are all out of tries.");    
return 0;
```

}

***And this is my list of errors:***
Compilation error   time: 
0 memory: 0 signal:0

prog.c: In function 'main':

prog.c:9:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'If' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   If (Guess==28)
   ^

prog.c:10:4: error: expected ';' before 'printf'
    printf("Congrats! You have guess the number!");
    ^

prog.c:11:3: error: unknown type name 'Else'
   Else If (Guess!=28)
   ^
prog.c:11:17: error: expected ')' before '!=' token
   Else If (Guess!=28)
                 ^

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: `s/If/if/` Same applies to `Else`. C++ is case sensitive. So is C.

Comment: a google on some tutorials wont hurt.

Comment: I'm surprised you have (correct) lower-case `for`, but then trying to use upper-case `If` and `Else`. I'm voting to close this as a typographical error.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome.  :)  I would never have thought to even try capitalizing reserved words like that! :)

Comment: and C != C++. In general, tag only the language you are actually writing/compiling.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: I suspect he might be coming from a Visual Basic background; I don't know if that language has case-sensitive keywords or not, but I *do* know it is (at the very least) a recommended practice to capitalize them (`If`, `Dim` and similar).

Comment: @TimČas It made my day. :)

Comment: @put_on_hold_folks: Why do you put this on hold? It is a stupid beginner mistake to capitalize if as If but still - we have a person that tried to do something on his own but failed. Then the idea is to help. How much would it take to answer "capitalize correctly" instead of closing the question? Bad style, IMO

Answer (score 6):

`if` and `else` clauses start with a lowercase letter. Actually all C and C++ reserved words start with a lowercase letter or a underscore.

Both C and C++ languages are case-sensitive.

Comment: I am not sure about C, but C++ has no restriction on reserved identifiers being lower case.

Comment: Both C and C++ are case sensitive.

Comment: It's not *entirely* true for C (think `_Generic`, `_Bool`, and `_Static_assert`), but I'm guessing you mean just the "usual suspects" like `for`, `if` and `while`.

Comment: @TimČas Right. Those look like keywords to me ;-)

Comment: The important thing to mention is case sensitivity.

Comment: @iharob It is important for answers not to contain incorrect information.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Technically reserved identifiers. Depending on who you ask (in particular when talking about grammars, programming languages and such), keywords != reserved identifiers, but that's irrelevant here.

Comment: @TimČas OK, they are reserved indentifiers and also keywords. All keywords may be lower case (they are in C++), but not all reserved identifiers are.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, keywords and reserved identifiers generally have no relation (other than they would both be ordinary identifiers without this special treatment). C actually has no keywords in the PL research sense at all (that I can think of), but again, that's another topic. The only language that comes to mind right now *with* keywords is C#.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Basically, reserved identifiers are treated specially *everywhere*, while keywords only sometimes (depending on context). `value` is a keyword in C# because it only exists within `set { ... }` (and maybe `get` ... not sure, I'm not a big fan of C#). Outside of `set`, you can do things like `int value = 5;`.

Comment: @TimČas The C11 standard even has a list of keywords. So C has keywords. But not all of them are lower case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70660/discussion-between-tim-cas-and-juanchopanza).

Comment: @TimČas Look, all the identifiers you listed in your first comment are in the C standard's list of keywords. That makes them keywords as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well, I tried moving it to chat, and that failed, so I'm ending this here and now. You can check online sources yourself though.

Comment: @TimČas There's nothing more to check.